# deciphering a surname

Tags: handwriting

I read *Carl --glin zu Lindensee* but would like an expert opinion on the beginning of the surname. I would like it to read *Reglin**, but I just can't see it that way.[image]*

Comment: I read "Koglin"; the name is [present](https://www.google.com/search?q=Koglin+Dortmund) in or around Dortmund today. Do you have circumstantial reasons to expect "Reglin"?

Comment: (Sorry for mixing up Dortmund and Darmstadt in the comment)

Comment: Yes -- the photo belonged to the Reglin family, who lived in the Lindensee vicinity. Their son Carl (b. 1841) was of the correct age to be the soldier pictured in the photo on the other side of this image.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the parts you already deciphered and read

> Carl Koglin zu Lindensee

Bodo Koglin's very detailed [website](https://hoelkewiese.de/index.html) traces the [origin](https://hoelkewiese.de/Genealogie%20Koglin/Namensherkunft.html) of the surname in Pomerania/West Prussia and provides more genealogical info, including [distribution over time](https://hoelkewiese.de/Genealogie%20Koglin/Verbreitung%20Koglin.html).

There was significant emigration to other Prussian and German regions, even *before 1945*. (I reckon the time frame of your photo as ca. 1870-1910.)